# How to write test case for JSR-352 style Spring Batch Job

Tags: java, spring, unit-testing, spring-batch

I have a spring batch job configured and running using [JsrJobOperator](http://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/apidocs/org/springframework/batch/core/jsr/launch/JsrJobOperator.html). There is a META-INF/batch.xml file which defines the batch-artifacts, and my job is defined in an XML file inside META-INF/batch-jobs folder (See [Archive-loader](http://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/reference/html/jsr-352.html#dependencyInjection) here). It works fine and now I want to write a unit test for this.

I tried using [JobLauncherTestUtils](https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/apidocs/org/springframework/batch/test/JobLauncherTestUtils.html). But looks like it is unable to locate my job.

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [org.springframework.batch.core.Job] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {}
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.raiseNoSuchBeanDefinitionException(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1373)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1119)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1014)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredMethodElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:618)
... 63 more
```

Here is my test program:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
 @ContextConfiguration(locations = {
    "classpath:META-INF/batch.xml",
    "classpath:test-context.xml"})
  public class MyUnitTest {


@Autowired
JobLauncherTestUtils jobLauncherTestUtils;


@Test
public void testSetup() throws Exception {
    JobExecution jobExecution =  jobLauncherTestUtils.launchJob();
    Assert.assertEquals(jobExecution.getStatus(), BatchStatus.COMPLETED);
}

}
```

And my test-context.xml

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xsi:schemaLocation="
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.2.xsd">


<bean class="org.springframework.batch.test.JobLauncherTestUtils">
    <!--<property name="job" value="ACER"/> => If I uncomment this, I get Failed to convert property value of type [java.lang.String] to required type [org.springframework.batch.core.Job], maybe there is a way to refer to the Job somehow?-->
</bean>

  <bean id="transactionManager"
      class="org.springframework.batch.support.transaction.ResourcelessTransactionManager" />


<bean id="jobLauncher"
      class="org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.SimpleJobLauncher">
    <property name="jobRepository" ref="jobRepository" />
</bean>


<import resource="database.xml" />

<bean id="jobOperator"
      class="org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.SimpleJobOperator"/>
<bean id="jobExplorer"
      class="org.springframework.batch.core.explore.support.JobExplorerFactoryBean">
</bean>

<bean id="jobRegistry"
      class="org.springframework.batch.core.configuration.support.MapJobRegistry" />

<bean id="jobRepository"
      class="org.springframework.batch.core.repository.support.JobRepositoryFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    <property name="transactionManager" ref="transactionManager" />
    <property name="databaseType" value="mysql" />
</bean>
</beans>
```

Question: How to write junits for JSR-352 style batch jobs, Am I on track by trying to use JobLauncherTestUtils?